# In MS Access, How do I extract multiple values in a single column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I parse multiple values out of a single column?
The problem is that multiple values are surrounded by extraneous (for my purposes) data.
Example:

```
Select * from my_table:
Fname   Lname    Data
Fred    Smith    @3aXXXX;Name:AA;@43deXXXX;Name:BB;@5433ed9;NAME:ABC;*#!XXXXXXXX;NAME:MyPetDog;@#IDXXXX
```

For the Data column, I want to extract all the values following the "Name:" fields from the column.  That would be the text following **"Name:"** and preceding **";"**.  In the example above:

```
Select Fname, Lname, [DATA] from my_table

Fname   Lname    [*Parsed* DATA]
Fred    Smith    AA,BB, ABC, MyPetDog
```

Solving the above Would be a tremendous help.  However, what I would really like to do a lookup/replace (SWITCH, etc.) each of the values returned from the string:

```
Fname   Lname    [Translated DATA]
Fred    Smith    Airport, Bus Station, Restaurant, FIDO
```

I apologize for using notional data.  My actual script (on another network) involves several table joins to get to the column DATA.  I just can't figure out how to extract the specific values from this large string (other that to extract the full data set and use AWk or MS Excel to cleanup the data afterwards).

Appreciate any assistance or tips on solving this.

Kevin L.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating a small VBA function that takes the "ugly" data and splits it out using the `Split` function. Something like:

```
Public Function fSplitData(strData As String) As String
    Dim aData() As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    aData = Split(strData, ";")
    For lngLoop1 = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        If Left(aData(lngLoop1), 5) = "Name:" Then
            fSplitData = fSplitData & Mid(aData(lngLoop1), 6) & ","
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
    If Right(fSplitData, 1) = "," Then fSplitData = Left(fSplitData, Len(fSplitData) - 1)
End Function
```

This gives the required output of:

```
AA,BB,ABC,MyPetDog
```

And, rather than just concatenating the extracted value, you could use a recordset to get the data from a lookup table. In your case, as you only have 8 values, you could just use `If` within the code:

```
Public Function fSplitData(strData As String) As String
    Dim strLookup As String
    Dim aData() As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    aData = Split(strData, ";")
    For lngLoop1 = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        If Left(aData(lngLoop1), 5) = "Name:" Then
            strLookup = Mid(aData(lngLoop1), 6)
            If strLookup = "AA" Then
                fSplitData = fSplitData & "Airport,"
            ElseIf strLookup = "BB" Then
                fSplitData = fSplitData & "Bus Station,"
            ElseIf strLookup = "ABC" Then
                fSplitData = fSplitData & "Restaurant,"
            ElseIf strLookup = "MyPetDog" Then
                fSplitData = fSplitData & "FIDO,"
            End If
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
    If Right(fSplitData, 1) = "," Then fSplitData = Left(fSplitData, Len(fSplitData) - 1)
End Function
```

You can then use this function in a query, just like you would use a standard Access function. So your SQL would look like:

```
SELECT 
FName, 
LName, 
Data, 
fSplitData([Data]) AS TranslatedData
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response...However, I have no idea how to test this in my Access db?  However, I like the idea of doing a lookup and based on above I did try to DECODE, but assess uses "SWITCH".  My "NAME:" values are limited to eight values, so I added:

Comment: I've modified the code to just use a series of `If` statements to "translate" the data, and shown how the function can be used in a query.

Comment: Editor's note: please try to stick to technical writing here as much as you can. There is a community preference to not add "regards" and other sign-offs at the end of posts, and it is generally removed by editors. Apologies if you have not met with this type of edit until now - it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Applecore, I have a almost working solution (though not likely the best solution):

```
SELECT Fname,
       Lname,
       SWITCH(data like "*AA*","Airport")&", "&
       SWITCH(data like "*BB*", "Bus Station")&", "&
       SWITCH(data like "*ABC*", "Restaurant")&", "&
       SWITCH(data like "*MyPetDog*","FIDO") as DATA

Fname   Lname    [Translated DATA]
Fred    Smith    Airport, Bus Station, Restaurant, FIDO
```

The only problem is,if a value is NOT there, then I get extra commas.  For example, if BB is the only value present, then I get:

```
Fname   Lname    [Translated DATA]
Fred    Smith    , Bus Station, ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as @AppleCore suggests, use an external function to avoid the mess.

```sql
SELECT 
    Fname, 
    Lname, 
    CleanField([Data]) AS TranslatedData
FROM 
    my_table;
```

Copy-paste the function (using `Select Case ..` for the conversion) into a new module, go to menu *Debug, Compile*, and save the module as, say, Module1_:

```vb
Public Function CleanField(ByVal Value As String) As String

    Dim Parts   As Variant
    Dim Index   As Integer
    Dim Part    As String
    Dim Text    As String
    
    Parts = Split(";" & Value, ":")
    For Index = LBound(Parts) To UBound(Parts)
        Part = Split(Parts(Index), ";")(0)
        
        Select Case Part
            Case Is = "AA"
                Part = "Airport"
            Case Is = "BB"
                Part = "Bus station"
            Case Is = "ABC"
                Part = "Restaurant"
            Case Is = "MyPetDog"
                Part = "FIDO"
        End Select
        
        If Part <> "" Then
            If Text <> "" Then
                Text = Text & ", "
            End If
            Text = Text & Part
        End If
    Next
    
    CleanField = Text

End Function
```

Example:

```
Fname   Lname   TranslatedData
------- ------- --------------------------------------
Fred    Smith   Airport, Bus station, Restaurant, FIDO
George  Olsen   Airport, Restaurant, Bus station, FIDO
Tina    Doe     Restaurant, Bus station, FIDO
```